# Delete Image on S3 bucket before uploading new image with the same name

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-storage

I have a model, that on save, it uploads my image to my S3 bucket. But I'm having some trouble when I want to reupload an image with the same name. (Example: when a logo updates it needs to be reuploaded)

Because the image already exists, Django extends the pathname with it's own generated extention to make it unique. We don't want that, we want to delete the existing image before uploading the new image. That way, the extention is no more.

I've tried removing my image first with the pre_save signal, but that just makes my imagefield empty

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=geo_models.Logo)
def remove_file_from_s3(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    instance.png.delete(save=False)
```

Any way of doing this?

Model:

```
class Logo(models.Model):
    logo_type_choices = Choices(
        ('ENTITY', _('Entity')),
        ('BRAND', _('Brand')),
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('logo')
        verbose_name_plural = _('logos')

    png = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name='{0} {1}'.format('png', _('image')),
        upload_to=get_upload_loc_png,
        validators=[validators.validate_png_extension],
        storage=storage,
        max_length=200,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    logo_type = models.CharField(choices=logo_type_choices, max_length=20)
```

Comment: What are you using to upload to AWS S3? boto3? Please share that part of the code.

Comment: Yes, I suppose so, I'm using the [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library.

Comment: How do you update the image exactly? Are you doing it through a `Form`? Through a `ModelForm`?  The image is attached to a specific instance so i assume you have multiple objects each with their own image right? Or you have a simple logo with a static name that has to be update routinely?

Comment: I'm using the Django-admin interface to edit the Logo model, I've updated my question with my model aswell

Comment: In your settings, do you have AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE set to false? It's optional, but if you have it, confirm it is set to True

Comment: Damn, it was that simple... thanks! @ScriptCode XD If you put it in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django-storages has an optional setting `AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE`.
By default, it is set to True ([reference](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html)). That is, by default files with the same name will overwrite each other. Set this to False to have extra characters appended.